# How to render markup so there's less FLOUT with a Vue Component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I need to render a list of items (server rendered), each item has a countdown timer.  When I just have my view component in each `dom` element there's nothing there, then `POP`, the view component renders the countdown... Now I know this value on the server side as well, is there some way to render it immediately such that the `vue` component will takeover the rendering? (Does that make sense)

Like the html from the server renders `50:32 (minutes, seconds)`, but then the view component takes over, removes it and starts the countdown `50:31`, `50:30`... etc etc.

I've tried passing the server val in as a prop and just rendering it inside the node, still pops (I assume because the component is rendering...)

Is this even doable, or am I stuck with a loader?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your relevant question, I propose an answer from what I understand.

you are trying to dynamically pass a property from the server to a view instance already created. This is not possible because Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the

Vue.set(object, propertyName, value) method:

```
Vue.set(vm.someObject, 'b', 2)
```

go on the official documentation of Vue to know more

here : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

hope that it puts you on the right track

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply.  So I'm not trying to pass a value from server to component, I can do that.  What I'm trying to do is have a value rendered to the page, then have it become a view component.  So the user doesn't see nothing, then POP, something.